# Ionic unit test in controller, spyOn not passing

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ionic-framework

It's a very simple test.. and it's not passing.. If someone can throw some light into this :)

This is the controller code (part of it) that needs to be tested

**AppCtrl**

```
    $scope.requestAuthorization = function() { requestAuthorization(); };

    if ($stateParams.requestAuthorization === true) {
        console.log('$stateParams.requestAuthorization');
        $scope.requestAuthorization();
    }
    function requestAuthorization() {
        console.log('requestAuthorization()');
        // more code here..
    }
```

**Test**

```
describe('AppCtrl', function() {
    var AppCtrl, $rootScope, $scope, $stateParams;

    beforeEach(module('myapp'));

    // disable ionic cache to avoid GET errors
    beforeEach(module(function($provide, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $provide.value('$ionicTemplateCache', function() {});
        $urlRouterProvider.deferIntercept();
     }));

    beforeEach(inject(function($controller, _$rootScope_, _$injector_, _$stateParams_) {
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $stateParams = _$stateParams_;
        AppCtrl = $controller('AppCtrl',{
            $scope: $scope
        });
        spyOn($scope, 'requestAuthorization');  
        $stateParams.requestAuthorization = true;
    }));

     it('$stateParams.requestAuthorization should be defined', function() {
        expect($stateParams.requestAuthorization).toBeDefined();
    });

    it('$scope.requestAuthorization should be defined', function() {
        expect($scope.requestAuthorization).toBeDefined();
    });

    // this test is not passing.. 
    it('should call requestAuthorization', function() {
        expect($scope.requestAuthorization).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

The function is actually being called, I can see the console.log in the console, but it's not passing.

Easy tests, all passing.. except the last one..

Thanks for your time :)

**NOTE**: There is a `$stateParams.requestAuthorization`, and a `$scope.requestAuthorization`. First one is boolean, the other a function, the function is not passing.

Answer (score 0):

In your beforeEach block, define the $stateParams before instanciate the Controller.

```
beforeEach(inject(function($controller, _$rootScope_, _$injector_, _$stateParams_) {
            $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
            $scope = $rootScope.$new();
            $stateParams = _$stateParams_;

            $stateParams.requestAuthorization = true;

            AppCtrl = $controller('AppCtrl',{
                $scope: $scope,
                $stateParams: $stateParams
            });
            spyOn($scope, 'requestAuthorization');  

        }));
```

Comment: Nope, not working :/, it's actually weird, I have a very similar test in another controller and it's working.. but not in this controller..